# Отмена вычислений функции при встроеном if

Tags: javascript

Как собственно выглядит код:

```
addLifes.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

        if (stats <= 0 || stats === 0) {
            this.;
            addLifes.style.background = 'red';
            alert('Must more level!');
        }

        lifes += 1;
        stats -= 1;
        statsCountLabel.innerHTML = stats;
        lifesLabelCount.innerHTML = lifes;
    });
```

Проблема акая. При 0 счете статов, нужно отменить вычисление. Как реализовать отмену материнской функции при дочернем if?

Comment: [условный оператор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)#%D0%A3%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)?

Comment: Добавить `return;` или же добавить в else

Answer (score 0):

Остановить работу функции можно за счет оператора `return`. Именно этот оператор является целью вычислений функции. В случае, если нет `return` функция выполняется до конца. Либо в Вашем примере можно использовать `else`, что тоже предотвратит выполнение вычислений.

**Вариант с return:**

```
 addLifes.addEventListener('click', ()=>{

    if (stats <= 0 || stats === 0) {
        //this.;
        addLifes.style.background = 'red';
        alert('Must more level!');
        return;
    }

    lifes += 1;
    stats -= 1;
    statsCountLabel.innerHTML = stats;
    lifesLabelCount.innerHTML = lifes;
});
```

**Вариант с else:**

```
 addLifes.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if (stats <= 0 || stats === 0) {
        //this.;
        addLifes.style.background = 'red';
        alert('Must more level!');
    }else{
       lifes += 1;
       stats -= 1;
       statsCountLabel.innerHTML = stats;
       lifesLabelCount.innerHTML = lifes;
   }

 
});
```

Comment: Можно ещё сделать так: `for (;(stats <= 0 || stats === 0);) { /* код */ ;break; }`.

Comment: @ΝNL993, можно, но не нужно. Я не вижу хорошего решение с циклом для примера, который подал автор. Только может усложнить код